# angular ui-select search functionality for list is not needed how to hide that

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-select

angular ui-select search functionality.

I don't want to use search list option, how can I hide that option.

My Demo : [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/CKHbiSQ4tZXTjOyxpyBK?p=preview)

```
> http://plnkr.co/edit/CKHbiSQ4tZXTjOyxpyBK?p=preview
```

I don't want this search option. default behavior of ui-select.
Please refer image.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are looking for ngHide?

Comment: edited my question please see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to disable feature of select an option by typing. You need to set `search-enabled` to `false`.
Documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select 
Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IwBWefw1TIq5hvOrR1hO?p=preview